# Filter spark dataframe based on previous month and year

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the below spark dataframe/dataset.

```
Column_A   Column_B
2020-12-31 1
2020-11-02 2
2020-10-01 3
2021-02-01 4
2021-01-05 5
2021-02-10 6
2021-02-11 7
2021-02-26 8
2021-03-01 9
```

I have to filter and keep only those records that are part of the previous month from the day of execution of script.

Suppose I am executing the spark program on 1st Jan 2021, the output dataframe should only have records from December 2020. If I am executing it today (march 1), then it should return all rows from Feb 2021.

Expected output:

```
Column_A   Column_B
2021-02-01 4
2021-02-10 6
2021-02-11 7
2021-02-26 8
```

How to achieve this in pyspark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter using `current_date` and `add_months` functions :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = df.filter(
    (F.month(F.col("Column_A")) == F.month(F.add_months(F.current_date(), -1))) &
    (F.year(F.col("Column_A")) == F.year(F.add_months(F.current_date(), -1)))
)

df1.show()
#+----------+--------+
#|  Column_A|Column_B|
#+----------+--------+
#|2021-02-01|       4|
#|2021-02-10|       6|
#|2021-02-11|       7|
#|2021-02-26|       8|
#+----------+--------+
```

Using `date_format`:

```
df1 = df.filter(
    F.date_format(F.col("Column_A"), "yyyyMM") == F.date_format(F.add_months(F.current_date(), -1), "yyyyMM")
)
```

Using `date_trunc`:

```
df1 = df.filter(
    F.date_trunc("month", F.col("Column_A")) == F.date_trunc("month", F.add_months(F.current_date(), -1))
)
```