# Is there a more efficient way to filter previous month's (or X previous months') data using Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Pyspark, so I apologize if this is a basic of a question. I have looked at a few StackOverflow posts (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66417767/1330974)), but I am still not sure if I'm following the best (most efficient) way of doing things here.

I have a dataframe and a string parameter/variable representing dataset date. Using the dataset date, I would like to filter data from the dataframe for the last 'X' month (for simplicity, let's just say I'd like to fetch just the last month's data). What I have tried is as below.

```
customer_panel_s3_location = f"s3://my-bucket/region_id={region_id}/marketplace_id={marketplace_id}/"
customer_panel_table = spark.read.parquet(customer_panel_s3_location)
customer_panel_table.show(20, False)

#+-----------+---------+--------------+------------+-------------+---------+-------------+-----------+
# |customer_id|region_id|marketplace_id|snapshot_day|45d_yield|plan_type|payment_offer|target_date|
# +-----------+---------+--------------+------------+-------------+---------+-------------+-----------+
# |493595720  |1        |1             |2021-12-31  |0            |ANNUAL   |PAID         |2023-02-11 |
# |277499930  |1        |1             |2022-01-04  |0            |ANNUAL   |PAID         |2023-02-11 |
# |790961616  |1        |1             |2021-12-28  |0            |ANNUAL   |PAID         |2023-02-11 |
# |2111203    |1        |1             |2022-12-14  |0            |MONTHLY  |TRIAL        |2023-02-11 |
# |4673190    |1        |1             |2022-11-30  |1            |MONTHLY  |TRIAL        |2023-02-11 |
# |2117974    |1        |1             |2022-12-15  |1            |ANNUAL   |PAID         |2023-02-11 |


dataset_date = '2023-03-16'
df_customer_panel_table = (
    spark.read.parquet(customer_panel_s3_location)
    .withColumn("dataset_date", dataset_date)
    .filter(F.date_format(col("snapshot_day"), "yyyyMM") == F.date_format(F.add_months(F.to_date(col("dataset_date"), "yyyy-MM-dd"), month_offset_for_snapshot_day), "yyyyMM"))
```

Is there a cleaner (more Pyspark-y) way of doing this? I felt like it's kind of clunky that I am converting `snapshot_day` (a date type column) to `yyyyMM` and thus, might be introducing inefficiencies in conversion, if any.

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DataFrame

```
+-----------+---------+--------------+------------+---------+---------+-------------+-----------+
|customer_id|region_id|marketplace_id|snapshot_day|45d_yield|plan_type|payment_offer|target_date|
+-----------+---------+--------------+------------+---------+---------+-------------+-----------+
|  493595720|        1|             1|  2021-12-31|        0|   ANNUAL|         PAID| 2023-02-11|
|  277499930|        1|             1|  2022-01-04|        0|   ANNUAL|         PAID| 2023-02-11|
|  790961616|        1|             1|  2021-12-28|        0|   ANNUAL|         PAID| 2023-02-11|
|    2111203|        1|             1|  2022-12-14|        0|  MONTHLY|        TRIAL| 2023-02-11|
|    4673190|        1|             1|  2022-11-30|        1|  MONTHLY|        TRIAL| 2023-02-11|
|    2117974|        1|             1|  2022-12-15|        1|   ANNUAL|         PAID| 2023-02-11|
+-----------+---------+--------------+------------+---------+---------+-------------+-----------+
```

Importing necessary package

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, floor, months_between
```

1. Adding a column with given date

```
dataset_day = "2023-03-16"

customer_panel_df = customer_panel_df.withColumn("dataset_day", lit(dataset_day).cast("DATE"))
```

2. Calculate the months between Snapshot date with the dataset day using `months_between()` function

```
customer_panel_df = customer_panel_df.withColumn("month_gap", floor(months_between("dataset_day", "snapshot_day")))
```

3. Filter last 10 months record

```
customer_panel_df.filter("month_gap <= 10").drop("dataset_day", "month_gap").show()
```

***Output***

```
+-----------+---------+--------------+------------+---------+---------+-------------+-----------+
|customer_id|region_id|marketplace_id|snapshot_day|45d_yield|plan_type|payment_offer|target_date|
+-----------+---------+--------------+------------+---------+---------+-------------+-----------+
|    2111203|        1|             1|  2022-12-14|        0|  MONTHLY|        TRIAL| 2023-02-11|
|    4673190|        1|             1|  2022-11-30|        1|  MONTHLY|        TRIAL| 2023-02-11|
|    2117974|        1|             1|  2022-12-15|        1|   ANNUAL|         PAID| 2023-02-11|
+-----------+---------+--------------+------------+---------+---------+-------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew my earlier approach was kind of messy. Your suggestion is perfect and exactly what I'm looking for. :)